# How to save and load an object position?

Tags: python, game-engine

I want to know if it is possible and how to save and load the object position using the same script that i used to save and load properties.
Here is the script: http://pastebin.com/aNZATwxX

Comment: It'd be better to paste the code directly in your question instead of linking to it because all contents of your questions (thus your script) should be available as long as your question is available, so basically as long as Blender Stack Exchange exists. [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help) you can see how to mark text as code.

Answer (score 1):

My reputation is too low to comment. But your link to the script is not working.

If the script is writing and reading from an external file, it should definitely be possible to modify it to also save the object position.

Try re-uploading the script.

Comment: Your welcome :)